# How to easily edit cell value in excel file using c#

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, cell

I added excel.exe to References so that I was able to bring up

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

at least that's where I think the functions are located.

But ive received a bunch of errors and I don't understand why.

Error   1   'Application' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Application' and 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application' C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs 19  13  WindowsFormsApplication1

anyone know wats up?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing this... 
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

then when you want to interact with Excel you can access it with Excel.Application.
Otherwise the compiler sees two Applications, and does not know which one you mean.
1st is the Forms.Application
2ns is the Excel.Application

these may help.. i do this when i encounter ambiguous references...

Comment: You can also be fully explicit, and refer to Excel through Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application, but Gian's solution is more convenient; you simply need then to write Excel.Application.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your question about the errors you're receiving but I've found the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com) project on codeplex a very easy way to interact with excel files. Additionally it's a lot easier to work with than the interop assemblies.

There are several good examples available to look through and the guy who maintains it seems to be very helpful.